# @Inject issues in AttributeConverter in JPA 2.2/Java EE 8/Glassfish v5

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi, jpa-2.2

JPA 2.2 should support `@Inject` in `AttributeConverter`, as described in the specification:

> Attribute converter classes in Java EE environments support dependency injection through the Contexts
>   and Dependency Injection API (CDI) [ 7 ] when CDI is enabled[51]. An attribute converter class that
>   makes use of CDI injection may also define lifecycle callback methods annotated with the PostConstruct
>   and PreDestroy annotations. These methods will be invoked after injection has taken
>   place and before the attribute converter instance is destroyed respectively.

But when I convert my JPA 2.1 conveter sample to JPA 2.2, it does not work.

The [original Converter](https://github.com/hantsy/ee7-sandbox/blob/master/jpa/converter/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/example/ee7/jpa/ListToStringConveter.java)  worked both Glassfish v4 and v5:

```
@Converter
public class ListToStringConveter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

//@Inject Logger log;

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> attribute) {
    if (attribute == null || attribute.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    return StringUtils.join(attribute, ",");
}

@Override
public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    if (dbData == null || dbData.trim().length() == 0) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    String[] data = dbData.split(",");
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}
}
```

To taste the injection support of `AttributeConverter` in JPA 2.2, I extracted the conversion logic to anther CDI bean. And tried to run the codes in Glassfish v5(Java EE 8 Reference implementation).

```
@Converter(autoApply = false)
public class TagsConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

//    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TagsConverter.class.getName());
//    
//     @Override
//    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> attribute) {
//        if (attribute == null || attribute.isEmpty()) {
//            return "";
//        }
//        return String.join( ",", attribute);
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
//        if (dbData == null || dbData.trim().length() == 0) {
//            return new ArrayList<>();
//        }
//
//        String[] data = dbData.split(",");
//        return Arrays.asList(data);
//    }

    @Inject
    Logger LOG;

    @Inject
    ConverterUtils utils;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "calling @PostConstruct");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy(){
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "calling @PreDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> attribute) {
        LOG.log(Level.FINEST, "utils injected: {0}", utils != null);
        if (attribute == null || attribute.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        return utils.listToString(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null || dbData.trim().length() == 0) {
            return Collections.<String>emptyList();
        }
        return utils.stringToList(dbData);
    }

}
```

And `ConverterUtils` class.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConverterUtils {

    public String listToString(List<String> tags) {
        return join(",", tags);
    }

    public List stringToList(String str) {
        return Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
    }
}
```

In the `TagsConverter`, the expected `ConverterUtils` are not injected, and always get null when called it, a NPE threw.

The complete codes can be found [here](https://github.com/hantsy/ee8-sandbox/tree/master/jpa-cdi).

**Update**: I found I had created [an issue on EclipseLink bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423402) 4 years ago.

Comment: There's no `beans.xml' to enable CDI? Which version of CDI?

Comment: Why not mention which jpa 2.2 provider you are using?

Comment: @DN1 I have motioned I'v tested the codes in Glassfish v5, which shipped EclipseLink 2.7.0.

Comment: @Rouliboy Since Java EE 7 , there is no need to enable CDI by bean.xml,it is enabled by default(of course most of time I would like add a bean.xml explictly in my codes). I have motioned the original codes worked both Java EE 7/Java EE8. I have provided link of the completed codes.

Comment: @DN1 Any help here?